# EE no screens found when startx

Tags: 19.10

All 
Running 19.10 Server on raspberry pi4 (4gb) with no issues when using CLI. I installed Ubuntu desktop latest version but when I do startx I get the ee no screens found ee error. I am doing it remotely via ssh. I tried Kde and xfce but get the same error. Fix ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with the Raspberry Pi4 (2GB).

Did you check the X server log file?
It should be located in `~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log`.

In my case it read:

```
...
(WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
(EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
...
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE)
...
```

So I installed the missing **fbdev** module (took me some time to figure out the exact name):

`$ sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-fbdev`

After that, `startx` started the desktop environment just fine. As for why this module was missing in the first place, I have no clue.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you. I also do not know why this was missing but you ended some hours of frustration.

Answer (score -1):

first thing you need to check your graph card information,for example "lshw -c display" or "lspci",the you have the BusID of graph card for example :pci@0000:01:00:00.After that You need to find /etc/Xorg/xconf in part of devices ,add one line BusID "PCI:1:0:0". Finally,reboot systsem.